# EmptyStackException in getting current path for file manager although initialize path

Tags: java, android, path, stack

I made a file manager app and when I try to run it I get EmptyStackException in my method getCurrentDirectory(). In another method I initilized stackPath and I'm sure it's not empty.
Here's my code:

```
 public void initialisePathStackWithAbsolutePath(boolean choice, File file) {
    if (!choice)
        return;
    File dir = new File(String.valueOf(file));
    ArrayList<File> temp = new ArrayList<>();
    File root = new File("/");
    while (!dir.equals(root)) {
        dir.getParentFile();
        temp.add(dir);
    }
    Collections.reverse(temp);
    for (int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++) {
        pathStack.push(temp.get(i));
    }
}
```

This is where I get error in logcat:

```
   public File getCurrentDirectory() {
    return pathStack.peek();
}
```

And this my variable:

```
 private Stack<File> pathStack;
```

Comment: it seems possible for pathStack to be empty, if `dir` equals `root`. Are you sure that `initialisePathStackWithAbsolutePath` is ever called with an argument, and that this argument is never `"/"`?

Comment: @ChrisWarrick nice point. Actually I never give it a thought. what do you suggest?

Comment: It’s hard to provide a general suggestion. Perhaps you want to use [Deque](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) and return null or some other default value, or perhaps you will need to design your code in some different way to account for those cases.

Comment: All I need is to get access to root path in order to make my app work. Thanks in advanced.